# Cannot export a function in C# DLL using unmanagedexports

Tags: c#, dll, unmanagedexports

I am trying to create a DLL using C#.
In order to export my function, I am using UnmanagedExports.

My Application has an output type of Class Library, and the Platform target is set to x86. Here is my code:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System;

class Test
{
    [DllExport("add")]
    public static int TestExport(int left, int right)
    { 
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

I build and get my DLL. When I run `dumpbin /exports Test.dll` using the visual studio command prompt, I don't see any functions being exported. Is there something I am missing to this?

Comment: That is a pretty typical mishap with that product.  Look in the Output window for a diagnostic message.  Beware that it is not compatible with VS2017.

Comment: @HansPassant I recreate the project with VS2015. No longer got the warning. I also had to create a x86 configuration, not just set Platform target to x86. Thanks!